# Pawn went forward, capturing pawn that stayed parallel. Chess.com bug?

Tags: rules, chess.com

I decided to play a game against a real player in chess.com app. I played black.

At some point of the game I had a pawn on f5 and white had a pawn on e5. White captured my f5 pawn with the e5 pawn by moving the e5 pawn to f6!.

Is that a bug or a feature? I played for a while with bots and can’t remember they made such tricky moves.

```
[fen "rnbqkb1r/p3pppp/2p5/1p2P3/3PpP2/8/PPP1Q1PP/R1B1KBNR b - - 0 1"]

1...f5 2. exf6
```

Comment: Something called En passant. Go to link for more info. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant

Comment: it's en passant. it's actually a common thing in r/anarchychess https://www.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/comments/kpc7ig/holy_hell/ or https://twitter.com/tombomp/status/1355234550155239426

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a legal capture using the "en passant" rule. According to the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018):

> 3.7.4.1  A pawn occupying a square on the same rank as and on an adjacent file to an opponent’s pawn which has just advanced two squares in one move from its original square may capture this opponent’s pawn as though the latter had been moved only one square.

Comment: @ЙцуееЦукен You will see that I have also edited your answer to include the positions and moves you describe using the replayer. The replayer is properly programmed to know the rules of chess and so it recognizes fxe6 as a valid move and displays the result as one would expect and as you describe in your question.

Comment: Wow, didn’t know about that feature, thanks in advance. Probably will accept Your answer